# Are Chow groups a birational invariant?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let us work in the category of smooth, projective varieties (say, over an algebraically closed field $k$).  If $X$ and $X'$ are birational, then do they have the same Chow groups?  Is there at least a canonical morphism, between the Chow rings of these?

Comment: Think of what happens to Picard groups when you blow up points in surfaces.

Comment: @Angelo: What DOES happen to them? Can something be said in the case where the surface has singularities? I know there is a theorem on divisor class groups (Hartshorne, II.6.5), but I'd like to know if anything can be said specifically about the Picard group.

Comment: To elaborate Angelo's comment. No they aren't birational invariants
because they get bigger as you blow up.

Comment: To topspin1617: please don't scream. Do you want to pose another question?

Comment: @Angelo: I'm not screaming, otherwise the entire comment would be in caps. I want to pose the question that I already posed. What happens to Picard groups (in general, of singular surfaces) when you blow up (at singular points in particular, I guess)?

Comment: I don't know if there is a general result for the Picard group of a blowup. However, in the simplest cases (say, if you blow up a smooth point on a surface) the answer is known, and is sufficient to address the original question.

Comment: There is a general result for the blow-up along a regular embedding: in a quasi-compact quasi-separated (e.g. noetherian separated) scheme, if you blow-up a codimension at least 2 regularly embedded connected subscheme, the Picard group of the blow-up will be the original one with an extra copy of $\mathbb Z$. N.B. I assume quasi-compact and quasi-separated because I can only figure out a proof using derived categories of perfect complexes, where these assumptions play a role, but they might be unnecessary.

Comment: @Baptiste: If I remember correctly, that theorem is in Hartshorne? It seems that most of the theorems I can find on topic of Picard groups, class groups, etc. of varieties (specifically affine surfaces) see; to be for the nonsingular case. I've been looking at the same singularity for like a month now, trying to figure out what can be said (if anyone wants to help/is curious, it's a question I asked here). 

Comment: @topspin1617: I don't think this theorem is in Hartshorne. Where would it be? Actually, I needed to use this fact in a paper, and I was unable to find a reference in the literature, without weird unnecessary assumptions (like ample line bundles, etc.). Note that I'm asking for the embedding to be regular, but it is perfectly ok for both schemes involved to be singular.

Answer (score 8):

Proposition 6.3 of Colliot-Thélène (Jean-Louis) and Coray (Daniel),
*L'équivalence rationnelle sur les points fermés des surfaces rationnelles fibrées en coniques*, Compositio Math. **39** (1979), no. 3, 301–332, says that the Chow group of $0$-cycles of degree$\;0$ is a birational invariant of a smooth projective absolutely connected $k$-variety $X$ in the following two cases :

(i) the field $k$ is perfect and $X$ is a surface,

(ii) the field $k$ has characteristic $0$.

You can read the proof [at Numdam](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=CM_1979__39_3_301_0) (in French) or in Fulton's book on *Intersection theory* (in American).

Comment: In Fulton's *Intersection Theory*, **Example 16.1.11**, he proves this under the assumption that $k$ is algebraically closed (of arbitrary characteristic).

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn is too modest, he provided a wonderful explanation of this in an answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/241860/reference-request-on-birational-invariance-of-chow-group-of-zero-cycles-of-degre