# Reference request on birational invariance of Chow group of zero cycles of degree zero

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, birational-geometry, fundamental-group, algebraic-cycles

Let $CH_0(X)^0$ denote the group of zero cycles of degree zero modulo rational equivalence.

I am looking for a reference for the following fact:
If $X$ and $Y$ are smooth and projective varieties over a finite field and we suppose they are birational, then the groups $CH_0(X)^0$ and $CH_0(Y)^0$ are isomorphic.

As a second question, let $k$ denote the base field and set
$$
\pi_1^{ab}(X)^0 := \text{ker}[\pi_1^{ab}(X) \rightarrow \pi_1^{ab}(k)].
$$
Then, with the same assumptions on $X$ and $Y$, $\pi_1^{ab}(X)^0$ and $\pi_1^{ab}(Y)^0$ should be isomorphic.

For the first fact, I have found a reference for the case of dimension 2 in the answer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81510/are-chow-groups-a-birational-invariant) question (which links to a 1979 paper of Colliot-Thélène and Coray). The cases of dimension 1 and 0 are obvious. However, I have failed to find a reference for the case of general dimension. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not know references.  Both of these follow fairly quickly from well-known results: the Lang-Nishimura theorem for the first, and the "Purity Theorem" (SGA 2, Exp. X, Thm. 3.4, p. 118) for the second.

Comment: Thanks @JasonStarr , I have indeed managed to solve it for $\pi_1$ using your comment!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A reference for birational equivalence of $CH_0$ is Fulton's *Intersection Theory* [1], **Example 16.1.11**. In the example, he makes the assumption that $k$ is algebraically closed, but he never uses it. Since the argument is fairly short, let me repeat it here.

> **Theorem.** Let $k$ be a field, and let $X$ and $Y$ be smooth proper $k$-varieties. If $X$ and $Y$ are birational, then $CH_0(X) \cong CH_0(Y)$.

*Proof.* Let $f \colon X \dashrightarrow Y$ be a birational map. Let $\Gamma \subseteq X \times Y$ be the closure of the graph. Then $\Gamma$ defines maps
\begin{align*}
f_* \colon CH_0(X) &\to CH_0(Y)  & f^* \colon CH_0(Y) &\to CH_0(X)\\
a &\mapsto \pi_{Y,*}(\Gamma \cdot \pi_X^* a),  & b &\mapsto \pi_{X,*}(\Gamma \cdot \pi_Y^* b).
\end{align*}
The composition $f^* \circ f_*$ (resp. $f_* \circ f^*$) is given by the cycle $\Gamma^\top \circ \Gamma := \pi_{13, *} (\pi_{12}^* \Gamma \cdot \pi_{23}^* \Gamma^\top)$ on $X \times X$ (resp. by $\Gamma \circ \Gamma^\top$ on $Y \times Y$); see [*loc. cit.*, **Def. 16.1.1** and **Prop. 16.1.2(a)**] for details.

Let $V \subseteq Y$ be an open such that $f$ induces an isomorphism $f^{-1}(V) \stackrel\sim\to V$. Let $U = f^{-1}(V)$, $Z = X \setminus U$, and $W = Y \setminus V$. I claim that the cycle $\varepsilon := \Gamma^\top \circ \Gamma - \Delta_X$ is supported on $Z \times Z$. By the short exact sequence of [*loc. cit.*, **Prop. 1.8**], it suffices to show that the restriction of $\varepsilon$ to $S := X \times X \setminus Z \times Z = X \times U \cup U \times X$ is zero. Let
$$T := (X \times Y \times U) \cup (U \times Y \times X) = \pi_{13}^{-1} (S).$$
Then the restriction of $\varepsilon$ to $S$ is the pushforward along $\pi_{13}$ of
$$\left.\left(\pi_{12}^* \Gamma \cdot \pi_{23}^* \Gamma^\top\right)\right|_T.\tag{1}$$
We can compute the latter as
$$\left.\left(\pi_{12}^* \Gamma\right)\right|_T \cdot \left.\left(\pi_{23}^* \Gamma^\top\right)\right|_T.$$
This is a proper intersection, and the intersection is equal to the 'diagonal'
$$\left\{(a,b,c) \in U \times V \times U\ \big|\ f(a)=b=f(c)\right\}.$$
Indeed, the intersection agrees with this set on both $X \times Y \times U$ and $U \times Y \times X$.

Then the pushforward of (1) is $\Delta_U$. Hence $\varepsilon$ vanishes on $S$, so it is supported on $Z \times Z$. In particular, the projections $\pi_{1,*} \varepsilon, \pi_{2,*} \varepsilon \in CH_*(X)$ are supported on $Z$.

The punchline is that $\varepsilon$ acts as the identity on $CH_0(X)$ by the moving lemma. Indeed, any $0$-cycle $a$ on a smooth variety can be moved away from $Z$, so the intersection $\pi_1^* a \cdot \varepsilon$ is zero.

This proves that $f^* \circ f_*$ is the identity, and by symmetry the same holds for $f_* \circ f^*$. $\square$

**Remark.** It is even true that $CH_0$ is a stable birational invariant: if $X$ and $Y$ are smooth and proper varieties with $X \times \mathbb P^n \stackrel\sim\dashrightarrow Y \times \mathbb P^m$, then $CH_0(X) \cong CH_0(Y)$. (The only thing left to prove is that $CH_0(X) \cong CH_0(X \times \mathbb P^1)$, since we already know the result for birational varieties.)

---

**Remark.** The reason Fulton only proves the theorem for algebraically closed fields is that Fulton only proves the moving lemma over those fields. For a proof of the moving lemma over arbitrary fields, see Roberts's appendix to the Oslo 1970 Algebraic Geometry proceedings [2] (finite fields are addressed separately).

**References:**

[1] **Fulton, William**. Intersection theory (second edition). Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete. 3. Folge. *Springer-Verlag*, Berlin, 1998. ISBN: 3-540-62046-X; 0-387-98549-2. [MR1644323](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1644323)

[2] **Roberts, Joel**. Chow's moving lemma. Appendix 2 to: "Motives" by Steven L. Kleiman. *Algebraic geometry, Oslo 1970 (Proc. Fifth Nordic Summer School in Math.)*, pp. 89--96. *Wolters-Noordhoff*, Groningen, 1972. [MR0382269](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0382269)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this helps a lot since Fulton is really concise at this point!

Comment: Can I ask you to clarify one point? We write $\epsilon$ for the difference between the correspondence $\Gamma^{\top} \circ \Gamma$ and the identity correspondence $\Delta_X$. Why are the projections $\pi_{1*}\epsilon, \pi_{2*}\epsilon$ supported on $Z$?

Comment: The restrictions of both $\Gamma^\top \circ \Gamma$ and $\Delta_X$ to $U \times U$ are equal to $\Gamma_U$, hence their difference vanishes on $U \times U$. But the difference is supported on $U \times U \cup Z \times Z$, hence has to be supported on $Z \times Z$.

Comment: Great, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: A subtle point came up. To say that the cycle $\Gamma^\top \circ \Gamma$ is supported on $U \times U \cup Z \times Z$ we are implicitly using that $\Gamma^\top$ and $\Gamma$ are meeting properly (otherwise it would only be defined as a cycle class, not as a cycle). Can you give an argument/hint on why this should hold? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Joachim: you're right, this is a problem. In fact, I don't think they intersect properly: if $X \to Y$ is the blowup of $\mathbb P^3$ at a point $P$ with exceptional divisor $E$, then $\pi_{12}^*\Gamma \cap \pi_{23}^*\Gamma^\top$ contains $E \times P \times E$, which has the wrong dimension. I will provide a different and more careful argument.

Answer (score 3):

Using Jason Starr's comment I was able (I think) to figure out the case of $\pi_1(X)^0$. For anyone who stumbles across this with the same question in mind I add a sketch of the proof in an answer. For the experts, if you feel like leaving a comment whether my reasoning is correct, that would be great.

Let $\phi: X \rightarrow Y$ be a rational map, i.e. defined on some open $U \subset X$. Because $X$ is normal, $Z := X \backslash U$ has codimension at least two. This means the dimenson of the ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,z}$ is at least two for each point $z \in Z$. But then this local ring is pure (SGA 2, Exp. X, Thm 3.4), which in turn implies the couple $(X,Z)$ is pure (SGA 2, Exp. X, prop. 3.3), so that the categories $\operatorname{FEt}(X)$ and $\operatorname{FEt}(U)$ are equivalent.

Since $X$ and $Y$ are birational, we can find an open $V \subset Y$ such that $U$ is isomorphic to $V$ and in the same way we show $V$ and $Y$ have the same \'etale coverings. This shows $\pi_1(X) = \pi_1(U) = \pi_1(V) = \pi_1(Y)$ as desired, which proves in particular what I wanted to show.

Comment: This is incomplete. But it is in SGA 1 exp. X cor 3.4 anyway.