# Blow-up and the Chow group of zero cycles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, algebraic-cycles

Let $\tilde{X}\to X$ be a blow-up of a variety $X$ (over an algebraically closed field).

Is it true that the Chow group of zero cycles of $\tilde{X}$ is isomorphic to that of $X$? What if $X$ is a smooth variety?

Comment: The accepted answer at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/241860/reference-request-on-birational-invariance-of-chow-group-of-zero-cycles-of-degre proves birational invariance of $CH_0$ for smooth proper varieties (over any field).

Comment: To add one note to that answer: the result fails for some singular varieties $X$.  For instance, for a smooth plane curve $Y\subset \mathbb{P}^2_k$ of degree $d\geq 3$, for $X\subset \mathbb{P}^3_k$ a projective cone over $Y$, then $\text{CH})_0(X)\xrightarrow{\text{deg}}\mathbb{Z}$ is an isomorphism, because every point is rationally equivalent to the vertex of the cone.  However, for the blowing up of the vertex, $\widetilde{X}$ is a projective bundle over $Y$.  Thus, $\text{CH}_0(\widetilde{X})\to \text{CH}_0(Y)$ is an isomorphism, and $\text{CH}_0(Y)$ equals $\text{Pic}(Y)$.

Comment: @JasonStarr: I would like to say that Hacon-McKernan's proof of Shokurov's conjecture implies that if $X$ is log terminal, then $CH_0 \tilde{X}$ is still isomorphic to $CH_0 X$. (So your counterexample is somehow as good as one can do.) Maybe I am missing a subtlety.

Comment: @potentiallydense.  Yes, that is correct (assuming that the characteristic is zero, smiley-face).  The class of singularities such that $\text{CH}_0(\widetilde{X})\to \text{CH}_0(X)$ is an isomorphism, even after base change of $k$ to an arbitrary (not necessarily algebraically closed) extension is one of the key ingredients in the work of Voisin, Colliot-Th'el`ene -- Pirutka, etc., on non-stable rationality via specialization of decompositions of the diagonal.